# C# coercion operator?

Tags: c#, linq, automapper, linq-expressions

I got this test:

```
[Fact]
public void EverythingIsMappedJustFine(){
  new AutoMapperTask().Execute();
  Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

It throws a bit strange exception:

> Test 'Unit.Web.Bootstrap.AutoMapperFacts.EverythingIsMappedJustFine' failed:
>    System.InvalidOperationException : No coercion operator is defined
>    between types 'System.Void' and 'System.Object'.
>    at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetUserDefinedCoercionOrThrow(ExpressionType   coercionType, Expression expression, Type convertToType)
>   ...
>   at AutoMapper.DelegateFactory.CreateGet(MethodInfo method)

Unfortunately - I couldn't reproduce this on smaller scale and can't figure out what exactly is going on.

What is coercion operator?

---

[This](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/350477/expression-tree-with-a-usage-of-user-defined-conversion-compiles-incorrectly) might be useful. But I'm failing to extract and dumb down necessary information bits.

Comment: @vulkanino that does not help much :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I still don't know what exactly is coercion operator, but at least - <strike>I solved my problem</strike> found reason.

After some automapper debugging was able to reproduce problem:

```
namespace mappertest
{
    using AutoMapper;
    using NUnit.Framework;

    [TestFixture]
    public class FooFacts
    {
        [Test]
        public void MapToFizz()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(c => c.AddProfile(new FooProfile()));

            var foo = new Foo { Bar = "BarValue" };
            var fooModel = Mapper.Map<Foo, FooModel>(foo);

            Assert.AreEqual("BarValue", fooModel.Bar);
        }
    }

    public class FooProfile : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            CreateMap<Foo, FooModel>();
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
        public void Fizz() { }
    }

    public class FooModel
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
        public FizzModel Fizz { get; set; }
    }

    public class FizzModel { }
}
```

Quite simple as it turns out - source has method which is named just like destination property.

Comment: `Expression.GetUserDefinedCoercionOrThrow()` method uses `TypeUtils.GetUserDefinedCoercionMethod()` which looks for an implicit or an explicit operator defined in one of the two types where the result is the other type. So ˙coercion operator` seems to be an umbrella term that includes both implicit and explicit operators.